How do I automatically start sql script file in Docker?
I'm trying to start setup.sql file when I run this docker container.
I think the main problem is that it can't run this 'setup.sql' file. but I don't know why.
FROM jaspeen/oracle-xe-11g

ENV ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
ENV PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
ENV ORACLE_SID=XE

COPY setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql

EXPOSE 1521

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /etc/profile && sqlplus /nolog @/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql && /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start && tail -f /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/alert_XE.log"]

setup.sql
CREATE USER open_dn IDENTIFIED BY 1234;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO open_dn;

CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id NUMBER,
    name VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (1, 'John');
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Jane');
COMMIT;


I checked container's log
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Database not initialized. Initializing database.
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Setting up:
2024-05-10 11:08:58 processes=500
2024-05-10 11:08:58 sessions=555
2024-05-10 11:08:58 transactions=610
2024-05-10 11:08:58 If you want to use different parameters set processes, sessions, transactions env variables and consider this formula:
2024-05-10 11:08:58 processes=x
2024-05-10 11:08:58 sessions=x*1.1+5
2024-05-10 11:08:58 transactions=sessions*1.1
2024-05-10 11:08:58 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Configuration
2024-05-10 11:08:58 -------------------------------------------------
2024-05-10 11:08:58 ls: cannot access /u01/app/oracle/oradata: No such file or directory
2024-05-10 11:08:58 This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 11g Express 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Edition.  The following questions will determine whether the database should 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 will be used for database accounts.  Press <Enter> to accept the defaults. 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Ctrl-C will abort.
2024-05-10 11:08:58 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
2024-05-10 11:08:58 password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 initial configuration:
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Confirm the password:
2024-05-10 11:08:58 
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:
2024-05-10 11:08:58 Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
2024-05-10 11:10:33 Configuring database...Done
2024-05-10 11:10:33 Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done
2024-05-10 11:10:33 Installation completed successfully.
2024-05-10 11:10:33 Database initialized. Please visit http://#containeer:8080/apex to proceed with configuration
2024-05-10 11:10:33 Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance is already started
2024-05-10 11:10:33 
2024-05-10 11:10:33 Database ready to use. Enjoy! ;)

seems like there's no problem with it, but
SQL> select username from all_users;             

USERNAME
------------------------------
XS$NULL
APEX_040000
APEX_PUBLIC_USER
FLOWS_FILES
HR
MDSYS
ANONYMOUS
XDB
CTXSYS
OUTLN
SYSTEM

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS

12 rows selected.

there's no username 'open_dn'.
It means that SQL query didn't execute?
And I deleted image and container, rebuild, run
it says

2024-05-10 13:21:57 Database is not configured. Please run /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure if needed.


Wouldnt you want to run that script AFTER you have started the database. Looks like you are currently running it before the database will be brought up

There is a entrypoint.sh script inside the base image, you can customize the script, add the sql command after the "Enjoy! ;)" line, like below：
#!/bin/bash

# Prevent owner issues on mounted folders
chown -R oracle:dba /u01/app/oracle
rm -f /u01/app/oracle/product
ln -s /u01/app/oracle-product /u01/app/oracle/product
# Update hostname
sed -i -E "s/HOST = [^)]+/HOST = $HOSTNAME/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
sed -i -E "s/PORT = [^)]+/PORT = 1521/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
echo "export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe" > /etc/profile.d/oracle-xe.sh
echo "export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH" >> /etc/profile.d/oracle-xe.sh
echo "export ORACLE_SID=XE" >> /etc/profile.d/oracle-xe.sh
. /etc/profile

case "$1" in
        '')
                #Check for mounted database files
                if [ "$(ls -A /u01/app/oracle/oradata)" ]; then
                        echo "found files in /u01/app/oracle/oradata Using them instead of initial database"
                        echo "XE:$ORACLE_HOME:N" >> /etc/oratab
                        chown oracle:dba /etc/oratab
                        chown 664 /etc/oratab
                        printf "ORACLE_DBENABLED=false\nLISTENER_PORT=1521\nHTTP_PORT=8080\nCONFIGURE_RUN=true\n" > /etc/default/oracle-xe
                        rm -rf /u01/app/oracle-product/11.2.0/xe/dbs
                        ln -s /u01/app/oracle/dbs /u01/app/oracle-product/11.2.0/xe/dbs
                else
                        echo "Database not initialized. Initializing database."

                        printf "Setting up:\nprocesses=$processes\nsessions=$sessions\ntransactions=$transactions\n"
                        echo "If you want to use different parameters set processes, sessions, transactions env variables and consider this formula:"
                        printf "processes=x\nsessions=x*1.1+5\ntransactions=sessions*1.1\n"

                        mv /u01/app/oracle-product/11.2.0/xe/dbs /u01/app/oracle/dbs
                        ln -s /u01/app/oracle/dbs /u01/app/oracle-product/11.2.0/xe/dbs

                        #Setting up processes, sessions, transactions.
                        sed -i -E "s/processes=[^)]+/processes=$processes/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init.ora
                        sed -i -E "s/processes=[^)]+/processes=$processes/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/initXETemp.ora

                        sed -i -E "s/sessions=[^)]+/sessions=$sessions/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init.ora
                        sed -i -E "s/sessions=[^)]+/sessions=$sessions/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/initXETemp.ora

                        sed -i -E "s/transactions=[^)]+/transactions=$transactions/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/init.ora
                        sed -i -E "s/transactions=[^)]+/transactions=$transactions/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts/initXETemp.ora

                        printf 8080\\n1521\\noracle\\noracle\\ny\\n | /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

                        echo "Database initialized. Please visit http://#containeer:8080/apex to proceed with configuration"
                fi

                /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
                echo "Database ready to use. Enjoy! ;)"

                ## Run your customer sql file
                sqlplus system/oracle @docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql

                ##
                ## Workaround for graceful shutdown. ....ing oracle... ‿( ́ ̵ _-`)‿
                ##
                while [ "$END" == '' ]; do
                        sleep 1
                        trap "/etc/init.d/oracle-xe stop && END=1" INT TERM
                done
                ;;

        *)
                echo "Database is not configured. Please run /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure if needed."
                $1
                ;;
esac


and change the Dockerfile like below:
FROM jaspeen/oracle-xe-11g

ENV ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
ENV PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
ENV ORACLE_SID=XE

COPY setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 1521

Then rebuild you imange and run it, it is not so elegent since you have to change the entrypoint.sh but it works.
